# What is the return type of this code?

Tags: c#

```
public IEnumerable<ContactEntity> GetByCategory(ContactEntity Entity)
    {
        try
        {
            var _contacts = _unitOfWork.ContactRepository.GetMany((x=>x.CATEGORY==0 || x.CATEGORY==1 || x.CATEGORY==2 || x.CATEGORY==3 || x.CATEGORY==4 || x.CATEGORY==5));
            if (_contacts != null)
            {
                return _contacts.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            throw e;
        }
```

Comment: It is `IEnumerable<ContactEntity>` - as written in the method's signature --> `public IEnumerable<ContactEntity> GetByCategory(ContactEntity Entity)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the structure of a method header

```
[access modifier] [other modifiers] <return type> <name> (<parameter list>)
```

The things in [] can be omitted.

In the given code, this part is the header:

```
public IEnumerable<ContactEntity> GetByCategory(ContactEntity Entity)
```

Let's dissect this!

`public` is the access modifier. The method has no other modifiers, such as `static`, `virtual` etc. The name is `GetByCategory`. The parameter list is `(ContactEntity Entity)`. And the return value is `IEnumerable<ContactEntity>`!

So yeah, that's the answer.

**How to look for the return type of a method**

Next time, if you want to know the return type of a method, just look for the method name. The word immediately before the method name is the return type.

Here's a practice

What is the return type of this method?

```
public virtual Dictionary<string, List<int>> GetDictionary() {
    return null;
}
```

Answer:

> `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper

Comment: @Ajay If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking that checkmark/tick.